# Dummit and Foote 4.3.13: Find all the finite groups which have exactly two conjugacy classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Task: Find all the finite groups which have exactly two conjugacy classes.

Ideas:
I have been show the class equation and the orbit stabilizer formula and I wonder if I can put them to use. My general intuition so far is such;

1. Given $$|G|=\Sigma_{i=1}^{r}|\mathcal{O}_a|+|Z(G)|,$$ we need $\Sigma|\mathcal{O}_a|=2$ and $|Z(G)|\geq 1$ because the identity is always in the center. It could be that either each of the orbits are size 1 or a single order is size 2.
2. My other idea is to use the orbit stabilizer formula: $|G:G_a|=|\mathcal{O}_a|=2.$
3. Maybe split the possibilities into $G$ abelian and $G$ not abelian.

I'm new to this material so please let me know if either or these ideas are on the right track! Pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Every element of the center is its own conjugate class, and so if either the group is abelian or there is only one conjugate class other than the identity and the elements do not commute. Can you say anything about the size of conjugacy classes that might eliminate this second case?

Comment: Also, what you wrote in the body is inconsistent with the title. Are you looking for there to be two conjugacy classes, the number of elements not in the center to be 2, the number of non-trivial conjugacy classes to be, the size of each nontrivial conjugacy class to be 2, or something else? Because all these things are implied by different parts of your question.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, so to clarify what you're saying, either $|Z(G)|=2$ if $G$ is abelian or $G$ is not abelian. I'm not too sure about what else I can say. I have a proposition that says $a\in Z(G)$ iff $\mathcal{O}_a=\{a\}.$ But I feel like this puts me back into the first situation.

Comment: @Aaron, I'm not good with the terminology yet so I'm sorry about the confusion! For example, I didn't know that the center could be a conjugacy class. I want to find the two finite groups $G$ where both have exactly two conjugacy class.

Comment: The center either contains 1 or 2 elements (because if it had more than 2, then there would be more than 2 conjugacy classes).  If it contains 2, then the entire group is the center.  If $Z(G)=\{e\}$, what can you say?

Comment: The number of elements in a conjugacy class divides the order of the group, right? That should be useful.

Comment: Then the conjugacy class is of order 1. And yes what @GerryMyerson said...so then $G$ is of even order.

Answer (score 15):

Since $\{e\}$ is its own conjugacy class, let $\mathcal O_a$ be the other conjugacy class. The conjugacy classes of $G$ partition $G$, so $|G|=1+|\mathcal O_a|$.  But the size of a conjugacy class must divide the order of the group, $|\mathcal O_a|$ divides $|\mathcal O_a|+1$.  The only way this can happen is if $|\mathcal O_a|=1$.  Therefore, $|G|=1+1=2$, so $G\cong C_2$.

Comment: Thank you Aaron--the only bit I don't feel confident on is $C_2$. I believe $C_2$ is the class of $a$ so that would mean $C_2=\{e, a\}$?

Comment: $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order 2. There is only one group with exactly two elements (up to isomorphism).

Comment: Ok! I apologize as my prof does not use this notation. Thank you so much.

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen Some people prefer it to $\mathbb Z_2$ as that can stand for both the cyclic group of order 2 or the 2-adic integers.  $\mathbb Z/(2)$ is less ambiguous, but more cumbersome.  $C_n$ fits well with $D_n$ and $S_n$ for the most simple families of groups.

Comment: Why did the size of the conjugacy class of an element needed to divide the order of group? They are in general not subgroups of $G$. Best regards.

Comment: @Sarah a conjugacy class is the orbit of an element of G under the conjugation action. By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, the size of any orbit divides the size of the group.